# Не могу найти ошибку в коде (python)

Tags: python

[image: рез-ты]
[image: Задание]

```
def check_exam(arr1,arr2):
result = 0
for x in arr1:
    for y in arr2:
        if x == y:
            result += 4
        elif x != y:
            result += -1 
        elif y == None:
            result += 0
if result > 0:
    return result 
else:
    return 0
```

Comment: Переведите задание на русский язык и вставьте его текстом

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Первое. У Вас в исходниках `y` никогда не будет `None`. Там `y` может быть `== ''`

> Второе. `elif x != y` это условие срабатывает и в том случае, если `y == ''` и вы получаете `result += -1` вместо ожидаемого `result += 0`

> И Третье (самое главное) Вы сравниваете каждое проверочное значение экзамена с ответами на все вопросы этого экзамена.

```py
def check(arr1, arr2):
    result = sum(4 if check_val == answer else -1 if answer else 0 for check_val, answer in zip(arr1, arr2))
    return result * (result > 0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    exams = [
        (['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], ['a', 'c', 'b', 'd'],),
        (['a', 'a', 'c', 'b'], ['a', 'a', 'b', ''],),
        (['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'],),
        (['b', 'c', 'b', 'a'], ['', 'a', 'a', 'c'],)
    ]

    for test in exams:
        print(check(*test))
# 6
# 7
# 16
# 0
```

**UPD**
Вот так должна Выглядеть написанная Вами функция:

```py
def check_exam(arr1, arr2):
    result = 0

    for x, y in zip(arr1, arr2):
        if x == y:
            result += 4
        elif x != y and y != '': #  можно elif x != y and y:
            result += -1
        elif y == '':
            pass

    if result > 0:
        return result
    else:
        return 0
```